# why hql not inserting value getting from user input insted of selecting records from another table

Tags: hibernate, hql

Facts:

> HQL insert query is given to insert records into one DB table by selecting from another database table.

I understand, but what can we do when we want to store data coming from one model class?
Is it possible to store data into a table we are getting from the user side by HQL or is there an alternative?

I am a newbie so I'm sorry if this question is irrelevant.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi for data coming from Model class initially you need to set data in the model class and then  simply call the save(modelClassObject) using session .i will explain a simple example here suppose your model class is Student with attributes sid and sname.Then setvalues to the student bean and pass the Student reference to save method

```
SessionFactory sf=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
Session s=sf.openSession();
s.beginTransaction();
Student stu=new Student();
stu.setIs(101);
stu.setName("john");
s.save(stu);//This automatically persists the values of Student to the databases
s.getTransaction().commit();//Dont forget to commit transaction
s.close();//To close the Session
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need HQL for that, just [Session.save(model)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/Session.html#save%28java.lang.Object%29).